# Is there a way to align the text in a Edit Text by dip's within AXML?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a EditText in my app and i would like to align the text in it a bit more to the right is there a would to do this by axml?

Comment: Please check my code below @The Reptilian Army.Is it working for you.

Comment: Can you tell us how far you want to align your EditText's text to right? And can you provide your code and a Rough Img that we can have some IDEA about your question?@The Reptilian Army

Comment: Sure so i want to get the text in my EditText like 20 dp's further to the right not all the way to the right that's why android:gravity="right" would not work for me.

Comment: Thanks everyone i got the answer `android:paddingLeft="10dp"`

Answer (score 5):

To move your text to right side in your editText,you can use gravity and padding.

Check this here:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Test"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: That's the thing i don't want to move it all the way to the right i just wanted like 10 dp's but i can't find a way to do it.

Comment: then try using android:layout_marginRight="10dp",check if it is working or not@TheReptillianArmy

Comment: Thanks for the help unfortunatly that aligns the full EditText 10 dp's to the right i only want the text but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ok,there is another option you can do android:paddingRight="10dp" to slightly move your text in left direction,please check if it is working or not?@The Reptilian Army

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:gravity="right"` to the EditText

Comment: That's the thing i don't want to move it all the way to the right i just wanted like 10 dp's but i can't find a way to do it.